# Show child pages by menu order using Superfish Dropdown menu?

Tags: menus, dropdown, order

I'm using the [superfish dropdown menu](http://shailan.com/wordpress/plugins/superfish-dropdown-menu/) to create a drop down menu.

It's created the menu fine showing all the parent pages with the child pages in drop down's below.

The only problem I have is that the parent pages are by `menu_order` which is what I want but the child pages are not by `menu_order`. How can I make it show the child pages by `menu_order` so it mirrors the backend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I downloaded this plugin and took a look and it does work as advertised for me. The function it uses for displaying the page list is:

```
wp_list_pages(array(
        'sort_column'=>'menu_order',
        'depth'=>'4',
        'title_li'=>'',
        'exclude'=>$exclude
        )); ?>
```

Which is very straightforward and does very explicitly order the items via menu_order. However, because it's a core function subject to actions and filters, you might have another plugin (or maybe your theme) interfering with the ordering. Before getting carried away, first ensure that the Order is explicitly set on each page by editing (or quick editing) each page in question. If two pages are set to "0", they may order one way in the page list and another way in this widget.

If that checks out, I would check three more things in this order:

1. Make sure you're using the latest version of this plugin.
2. Make sure you're using the latest version of WordPress.
3. Try disabling all other plugins

Let me know how you make out here!

Answer (score 2):

Same as Matthews, tried it and works like a charm, I think you might have a plugin conflict. Alternatively, check if data is written to DB, but I really don't think that's the case, because the pages work fine

Comment: if your problems persist, you can hardcode those pages (sorry, this page doesn't allow me to post the code you need) or try another plugin, there are several with similar capabilities